# Have nginx set header on response according to environment var

Tags: docker, nginx

I use a simple Nginx docker container to serve some static files. I deploy this container to different environments (e.g. staging, production etc) using Kubernetes which sets an environment variable on the container (let's say `FOO_COUNT`).

What's the easiest way of getting Nginx to pass the value of `FOO_COUNT` as a header on every response without having to build a different container for each environment?

Comment: See this article also http://tarunlalwani.com/post/simple-parameterized-config-files-docker/. Discusses similar techniques given by @lifeisfoo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Out-of-the-box, nginx doesn't support environment variables inside most configuration blocks. But, you can use [`envsubst` as explained in the official nginx Docker image](https://github.com/docker-library/docs/tree/master/nginx#using-environment-variables-in-nginx-configuration).

Just create a configuration template that's available inside your nginx container named, e.g. `/etc/nginx/conf.d/mysite.template`.

It contains your nginx configuration, e.g.:

```
location / {
    add_header X-Foo-Header "${FOO_COUNT}";
}
```

Then override the Dockerfile command with

```
/bin/bash -c "envsubst < /etc/nginx/conf.d/mysite.template > /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf && nginx -g 'daemon off;'"
```

If you're using a `docker-compose.yml` file, use [command](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#command).

Kubernetes [provides a similar way to override the default command in the image](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/inject-data-application/define-command-argument-container/).

Comment: Thanks. Looks like I will have to dive into the Kubenetes docs to get it to generate the template on the pod.

Comment: You're welcome. Please accept the answer if it's solve your problem, this will help future visitors.

Answer (score 1):

This was made possible in nginx 1.19+. This functionality is now builtin.

All you need to do is add your `default.conf.template` file (it looks for *.template suffix) to `/etc/nginx/templates` and the startup script will run `envsubst` on it, and output to `/etc/nginx/conf.d`.

Read more at the [docs](https://github.com/docker-library/docs/tree/master/nginx#using-environment-variables-in-nginx-configuration-new-in-119), see an example here https://devopsian.net/notes/docker-nginx-template-env-vars/